# Why is python zip function builtin?

Tags: python, zip, built-in

I'm aware Python's `zip()` function is a builtin function written in C but I'm confused as to why they have bothered.

If I'm not mistaken, in Python, `zip()` can be rewritten as:

```
def zip(seq1, seq2):
    out = []
    for i in range(len(seq1)):
        out.append((seq1[i], seq2[i]))

    return out
```

(assuming `seq1` and `seq2` are the same size. The actual `zip()` will use the length of the smallest sequence)

This is a very simple piece of code, so I'm wondering, why have they made `zip()` a builtin function? I can only assume writing it in C is to make it faster - if that is the case, does anybody know how much faster? (I'm aware this will depend on the size `seq1` and `seq2`)

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: one way to make it fast using iterator

Comment: You could ask this about many builtin functions.  Why have `len` when you could just iterate over a list adding one to a counter for each element?

Comment: Well if you see any python scripts, will have many built-in methods who's implementation is easy but implementing all of this again just increases code width. I think these methods make python even more awesome as it makes it very readable.

Comment: Why write in python or C at all, when the same code can be written easily in assembler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [148]: def zipped(seq1, seq2):
        out = []
        for i in range(len(seq1)):
                out.append((seq1[i], seq2[i]))
        return out
   .....:     

In [149]: %timeit zipped(range(10), range(11, 21))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.06 µs per loop


In [152]: %timeit zip(range(10), range(11, 21))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 µs per loop
```

You can see that there is execution time difference(more than twice) in both `zipped` and inbuild `zip` function.

```
from itertools import izip
In [156]: %timeit list(izip(range(10), range(11, 21)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.98 µs per loop
```

While `itertools.izip` takes same about that of `zip`,

even for large data array:-

```
In [157]: %timeit zipped(range(10**5), range(10**5))
10 loops, best of 3: 77.3 ms per loop

In [158]: %timeit zip(range(10**5), range(10**5))
10 loops, best of 3: 31.5 ms per loop

In [159]: %timeit list(izip(range(10**5), range(10**5)))
10 loops, best of 3: 37.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I completely forgot about `%time`.

Comment: @RockJake28 while programming you should not concern much about time complexity of function, they are not much differ in respect but is always good to use built in when provide.

Comment: I have been using the zip function (obviously because its a lot cleaner) but as my code has developed I need a modified version of it, hence why I looked at rewriting it.